# Making buttons stick top and bottom in a label frame (AppJar Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to make the buttons line up horizontally rather than side by side in AppJar but I can't manage to get it to work

I have tried this so far:

```
    dashboard.startLabelFrame("Exams", row=2, column=0, colspan=1)
    dashboard.setSticky("ns")
    dashboard.addButtons(["Create exam", "Modify exams", "Delete exams"], None)
    dashboard.stopLabelFrame()
```

I used the setSticky method to try and make it stick to the north and south of the label frame, but still does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.addButtons()` function is designed to specifically align buttons side-by-side.

If you want to add buttons on top of each other, then use multiple calls to `.addButton()`:

```
dashboard.startLabelFrame("Exams", row=2, column=0, colspan=1)
dashboard.setSticky("ns")
dashboard.addButton("Create exam", None)
dashboard.addButton("Modify exams", None)
dashboard.addButton("Delete exams", None)
dashboard.stopLabelFrame()
```